# How do I troubleshoot Pass -- it is taking forever to unlock my gpg key

Tags: bash, password, gpg-agent

I'm using pass to manage/consolidate passwords, but it takes a very long time to even ask for my gpg passphrase. It can take up to 30 seconds, which doesn't sound like an eternity but it sure feels like an eternity.

I'd love to figure out what is going on.

When I run it with `strace` it dumps a bunch to the screen and then gets to:

```
access("/usr/bin/gpg2", X_OK)           = 0
stat("/usr/bin/gpg2", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=917032, ...}) = 0
geteuid()                               = 1000
getegid()                               = 1000
getuid()                                = 1000
getgid()                                = 1000
access("/usr/bin/gpg2", R_OK)           = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [INT CHLD], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [INT CHLD], NULL, 8) = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7fce7a0969d0) = 21903
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x4449b0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fce796db4b0}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fce796db4b0}, 8) = 0
wait4(-1,
```

It hangs out there and eventually I get a prompt for my gpg passphrase. Once I unlock my gpg key it spits the password right out, I don't understand why the prompt takes so long.

Comment: Do you have some sort of agent or keychain running?

Comment: I have gpg-agent.

Comment: If your agent flakes out and you call pass, you will see this sort of blocking. I'd be looking at the agent, not pass.

Comment: Are you running `pass` on a remote machine, e.g. via `ssh`?   If the gpg-agent on that remote machine is configured to try a GUI program first when asking for the password, you will get delays (or eventual timeout and fail).  Check the `pinentry-program` setting in your `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`.  There are also various debug settings you can enable in that conf file.

Comment: BTW, i use `pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-curses` because I mostly use `pass` and `gpg` from the command line (or from text programs like `mutt`) and i want it to work in a local terminal and over ssh.  I really don't care about a GUI for passphrase entry, so I've never bothered to find out how to get it to work reliably for both text-mode and GUI.

Comment: Do you get the same delay if you run the `gpg2` program to do any kind of key management operation, like `gpg2 --list-keys`?

Comment: Use `strace -f` to follow forked processes. The clone() call is forking the process, probably in preparation to execute another program. `strace -f` should help you see which.